# Hibernate: Kotlin array to Java array

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, kotlin

I'm using Kotlin and Hibernate with JPA entities. I've tried to implement the following solution: https://vladmihalcea.com/map-postgresql-enum-array-jpa-entity-property-hibernate/

I've ran into an issue with the TypeDef annotation. I'm essentially trying to write the following Java code in Kotlin:

**JAVA**

```
@TypeDefs({
    @TypeDef(
        parameters = {
            @Parameter(
                value = "sql_array_type",
                name = "SEAT_PROPERTY_ENUM"
            )
        },
        defaultForType = SeatPropertyEnum[].class,
        typeClass = EnumArrayType.class
    )
})
```

To make sure, I wrote the code in Java first and then converted it to Kotlin. It looks fine to me:

**KOTLIN**

```
@TypeDefs(
    TypeDef(
        parameters = [
            Parameter(
                value = "sql_array_type",
                name = "SEAT_PROPERTY_ENUM"
            )
        ], 
        defaultForType = Array<SeatPropertyEnum>::class,
        typeClass = EnumArrayType::class
    )
)
```

However, when I run my code and tests I get an error. The issue is the **defaultForType** property. After  decompiling my Kotlin code back to Java, `Array<SeatPropertyEnum>::class` has been converted to `SeatPropertyEnum.class`. It should have been `SeatPropertyEnum[].class`. What on earth is going on here?

Comment: have you tried replacing `Array<SeatPropertyEnum>::class` by `Array<SeatPropertyEnum>::class.java` ? Becaus kotlin ::class operator does not return a java class, but a KClass object, and I do not see how hibernate would handle it.

Comment: I get the following compilation error if I change to that:

`Expected type mismatch: inferred type is Class<Array<SeatPropertyEnum>> but KClass<*> was expected`

Comment: @amanin Rules for annotations are special, and in particular "If you need to specify a class as an argument of an annotation, use a Kotlin class (KClass). The Kotlin compiler will automatically convert it to a Java class, so that the Java code can access the annotations and arguments normally." https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html

Comment: Based on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-26568 it should work: "For example, `Array<String>::class` will be translated to `String[].class`."; I suggest reporting a bug.